# Error de sintaxis al dividir dos números

Tags: php, php5

Básicamente mi problema es que por algún motivo, la siguiente línea me da error de sintaxis:

```
class CalcCombined {
    private $CI;
    private static $QUANTITY = 100;
    private static $PERCENT_SALESBONUS = 10/100; // Línea de que da error
    private static $PERCENT_EBITDABONUS = 10/100;
```

El error de sintaxis que me da es exactamente este: `syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';'`

He intentado parsearlo a INT a FLOAT y no se soluciona el problema.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si quito el $ deja de ser una variable.

Comment: Cierto. Pues dale la vuelta, `static private`. Tengo el PHP algo *oxidado*

Comment: Algo no, bastante :') tienes errores de sintaxis en tus comentarios y de conceptos básicos en PHP

Comment: Afortunadamente, me mantengo suficientemente lejos de dicho *pseudo-lenguaje* :-)

Comment: Pues parece que hay algo que **no** nos estás contando ... eso que muestras no da ningún error, puedes comprobarlo: https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLKzknsbhYwTkxJ9k5PzcpMy81RaGaSwEICooyyxJLUhVUnD2tUQSKSxJLMpMVVAJDHf1CPEMiFWwVDA0MsKsJcA1ydvULiQ929HENdvL3Cw0Gq9YHaVDQ11fwObw2LzVRISVVobA0VSElUSG1qCi/CK9Rrk6eIS6OaGZx1Vr//w8A

Comment: Por eso lo estoy preguntando, es algo muy extraño y no sé qué puede estar pasando. Lo peor es que este error, lo devuelve el servidor y también me lo indica el editor de texto VS code.

Comment: Pero es que será *un pelín* difícil que nadie te pueda ayudar si el error no se puede reproducir ... eso quiere decir que es algo exclusivo de tu entorno: ¿ versión de PHP ? ¿ El error te lo da el IDE o el intérprete PHP ? ¿ Con PHPCli, con un módulo de Apache ? ...

Comment: @xelfury sí, está la clase cerrada. No subo el código completo porque es una clase bastante extensa.

Comment: @Trauma también he llegado a esa posible conclusión, que sea problema de la versión ya que esto no fallaba en PHP 7 pero tuvieron que hacer un downgrade al servidor a la 5.X y a partir de ahí empezaron los problemas.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta.

Comment: [edit] la pregunta y añade esos detalles. Con `PHP 5.4` el error **si** se reproduce.

Comment: @Trauma ya me han solucionado el problema más abajo. Gracias de todas formas ;)

Answer (score 5):

La manera en la que estás declarando la variable tan solo tiene sentido dentro del contexto de una clase.

Lo que estás haciendo es difinir un atributo para una clase, si tratas de declararla de esa manera fuera de una clase te va a aparecer el error que mencionas.

Te pongo un ejemplo donde tu manera de declarar tendría sentido:

**PHP**

```
class Ventas {
    private static $PERCENT_SALESBONUS = 10/100;
}
```

**EDIT**

El problema viene determinado por tu versión de **PHP**. Antes de la 5.6.0 no se permitían los atributos de clase calculados. Si necesitas hacer ese cálculo declara una función dentro de la clase que te la devuelva.

```
class CalcCombined {
    private $CI;
    private static $QUANTITY = 100;
    
    public function get_percent_salesbonus () {
        return  10/100;
    }
}

$CalcCombined = new CalcCombined();

echo $CalcCombined->get_percent_salesbonus();
```

Comment: Está dentro de una clase

Comment: Muchas gracias! solucionado

Answer (score 1):

El problema mayor es uno solo: **¿qué necesidad hay de declarar como valor calculado un miembro estático?**, pues ninguna.

La operación `10/100` será siempre igual a `0.1`, aquí, en Marte o en otra galaxia, eso espero :)

Entonces, la mejor solución es declarar el campo de esta manera:

```
private static $PERCENT_SALESBONUS = 0.1;
```

O sea, el resultado de `10/100`. No veo por qué complicarse queriendo declarar el campo como un cálculo.

Comment: Gracias! el proyecto es heredado y bueno, estoy encontrándome con estas perlitas en el código.

Comment: @JuliánPeñarandaAcevedo entiendo, pero supongo que tienes la posibilidad de irlo mejorando. El criterio es claro: Para datos que no varían no tiene sentido aplicar cálculos. Por el contrario, si alguno de los datos es variable, el `10` o el `100`, tienes que usar métodos. Si sólo el `10` es fijo, declaras una constante para ese valor, si sólo el  `100` es fijo, declaras una constante para ese valor, si lo que se debe aplicar como valor fijo es `0.1` declaras una constante para ese valor. En los métodos puedes combinar los valores fijos con los valores dinámicos.